# Global label starting with capital L in assembly with clang

Tags: assembly, clang, global-variables

I am trying to port a certain project that has C and assembly, and it was compiled on Linux before, with GCC. There is some assembly which looks like

```
LabelStartingWithCapitalL: ; .global LabelStartingWithCapitalL
    .4byte ...
```

The GCC assembler does not seem to care if global labels start with L, but clang tells me `non-local symbol required in directive`... I really need to keep these labels, since I want to change as little in the original source code as possible, and having to change this would involve me changing a lot of symbols. Is there a way to force clang to accept these types of labels as global labels, besides giving up and using a different compiler?

Comment: You can try putting the label into quotes.  On COFF and a.out targets, labels starting with `L` are not entered into the symbol table (on ELF targets, these start with `.L`).  If this happens on ELF targets, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @fuz it seems like wrapping the labels in quotes does not work, I could change them into .L and then the file assembles, but then I'd have to change it in a lot of other places as well, since then the name of the actual symbol is different, and I'd rather not do that...

Comment: You can set the asm symbol name independent of the C variable name with `int LotsaLuck asm("_LotsaLuck");`, in this case decorating it with a leading `_`.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels).  Of course, on some targets like MacOS or 32-bit x86 Windows, the asm name would already use a leading underscore per the ABI convention, in which case you'd *only* need to change the asm, not the C.  (A regex search/replace for tokens starting with capital L might work well.)

Comment: @PeterCordes that solution would probably work, but it's spread out over multiple files, and if possible I'd really rather find a solution that would not involve me changing all the labels

Comment: @Dennis Switching to `.L` is definitely not correct.  What operating system are you programming for?  If it is a COFF target such as Windows, then you should not use labels starting with a capital L, full stop.

Comment: @fuz: Windows x64 doesn't decorate symbols with a leading underscore.  https://godbolt.org/z/q4EojW8P8 shows MSVC using `LOL` as an asm symbol name for a global variable.  (vs. `_LOL` when targeting 32-bit).
 Is the object file format not called COFF for Windows x64?

Comment: @Dennis: Multiple files isn't harder with a good regex search/replace tool.  Even as simple as `sed -i s/.../.../g   **/*.h` Or `**/*.S` if it turns out you are now building for an ABI where C symbol names get leading underscores, so you need to change all asm symbol names, not just the ones starting with `L`.  Obviously use git or something to snapshot in case you need to roll back, and to examine the changes and maybe only commit some of them and discard others.  (`git gui` is good for interactive staging / unstaging of individual diffs.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Windows x64 is ECOFF.  That is interesting... shows that my knowledge is incomplete.  Traditionally, the UNIX assembler uses `L` for local (excluded from symbol table) labels.  This was changed to `.L` for ELF, but I was sure that it also applied to ECOFF, being based on COFF from AT&T UNIX and all that.